# UnicodeEncodeError when using python from ssh

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-3.x, ssh

I made a small application that prints unicode special characters(i.e. superscript, subscript...). When it runs locally there are no problems but when it runs in a ssh session I always get a UnicodeEncodeError. 
Specifically: `UnicodeEncodeError 'ascii' can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`
I tried different ssh clients, computers and double checked the sessions encoding but the result is the same.
This is really weird. Why does this happen? Is this really related to ssh?

Comment: Most likely because Python cannot determine the terminal encoding, and falls back to ASCII. See the http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html python Unicode Howto.

Comment: Does `python your_script.py | cat` work locally? Try `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python your_script.py | cat`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes, is working. Even without that enviroment variable set.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian With `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` it also work in ssh. Thanks.

Comment: @Rnhmjoj can you post the code where you get the string from input into a variable? And if you can, would be great to see in the code how you treat those string both input and output.

Comment: @PauloBu I take the string from the argv. You can see the code [here](https://gist.github.com/Rnhmjoj/5855334).

Comment: @Rnhmjoj One more thing, can you provide the arguments you're passing to the program and the traceback of the exception?

Comment: @PauloBu For example: `$ zalgo ac 5 Test`. The traceback is: `File "/usr/local/bin/zalgo", line 57, in <module> print("", zalgo, "", sep="\n"*(n//3))` and the exception is the same I wrote in the question.

Comment: what does [`test_io_encoding.py`](https://gist.github.com/5898423) print?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Everything is set to `US-ASCII` and `PYTHONIOENCODING` is None.

Comment: Is it literally `US-ASCII` or a lowercase `ascii` or `ANSI_X3.4-1968`? What is the output of `locale` command in bash?

Comment: Yes, literally `US-ASCII`. And `locale` gives `it_IT.UTF-8`(I'm italian)for everything except for `LC_ALL` which is empty.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be not your Python code, check your ssh ENV. LANG should be en_US.UTF-8 (containing UTF-8) not ASCII

Comment: `LANG` is set to utf-8. Setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` will solve the issue but the strange thing is that `sys.getdefaultencoding()` already return utf-8. So this shouldn't change anything.